# Parsing date reseting the timezone

Tags: java, date

I'm trying to set the timezone on Date object based on the airport.
it's reseting the time zone from EST to the local time zone CST when I parse it from String to date again.

```
 private Date formatDate(final Date date, final FlightStop stop) {
    DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy hh:mm aa zzz");
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(stop.getAirport().getTimeZone().getID()));

    try {
        LOG.debug("before parsing -> sdf.format(date) : " + sdf.format(date)); //03/03/20 10:45 AM EST
        LOG.debug("after parsing -> sdf.parse(sdf.format(date)) : " + sdf.parse(sdf.format(date))); //after parsing Tue Mar 03 09:45:00 CST

        return sdf.parse(sdf.format(date));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new Date();
    }
}
```

Updated:
Method call:

```
 public void sendMessage(final Date endingStopDate, final FlightStop endingStop) {
        Date endDate = formatDate(endingStopDate, endingStop);
        traveler.setDate(endDate);
```

Comment: Post the code where you are calling that method.

Comment: `Date` & company are an ugly mess with unintuitive APIs and mixing of unrelated information in a single class. Is it an option to use the `java.time` package? It might be complex, but it's as complex as time and dates are and no more than that ...

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the latter in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `ZonedDateTime` and `ZoneId`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Also don’t rely on three-letter time zone abbreviations, they are most often ambiguous and very often not true time zones.

Answer (score 3):

## `Date` is UTC

You cannot set a time zone for `java.util.Date`. That class represents a moment in UTC.

## *java.time*

You are using terrible date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

To generate string in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, call `toString`. `ZonedDateTime::toString` wisely extends the standard by appending the name of the time zone in square brackets.

To generate strings in other formats, use `DateTimeFormatter`. Search Stack Overflow to learn more. This has been covered many hundreds of times already.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( … ) ;
String output = zdt.format( f );
```

And parsing.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse( input , f ) ;
```

Do not exchange data values in custom formats. So do not generate and parse your custom strings back and forth. Exchange date-time values textually using only standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats. Usually best to adjust to UTC when doing so.

```
zdt.toInstant().toString()
```